# operator+() and operator+=()

Tags: c++

My C++ lecturer claims that whenever you have to implement the operator+() you must provide operator+=() as well?

I could not understand this logic, can someone explain me the logic behind this decision?

Comment: It makes sense to do both if you are going to do one, but there is no "must" for this.

Comment: No, nothing forces you to do that it is just recommended because it is logical.

Comment: The claim is unreasonable: Z operator + (X, Y)

Comment: It is like whenever you use a = b + c; it is possible that you might use a = a + b; that is a += b;

Comment: What your lecturer said is not true.  It's _recommended_ to implement thte `+=` operator as well because users might assume a class that can use a `+` operator might also assume they can use a `+=` operator.

Comment: Because you may have inconsistent behavior otherwise.

Comment: For an immutable value type, you definitely should _not_ implement `+=`. For a mutable value-holding type, you usually should implement it—and, more often than not, you should implement `+` in terms of copy and `+=`. But just flat out saying "always" is misleadingly incomplete at best. The reason for that "usually" is just that most mutable types for which `+` makes sense from a user point of view, `+=` does too. After all, you can do `i += 1` for an `int`, so why not your type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lecturer is wrong.

The fact that you can sum two objects forming a new third object (which is what binary `+` does) does not necessarily imply that your objects are supposed to be modifiable "in place" (which is what `+=` does).

In other words, if and only if your class supports the concept of being *modifiable in place*, then it is a fairly good programming practice to provide `+=` whenever you provide both `+` and `=`. But in any case there's no "must" here.